# I don't find any code about getting all images to html web page

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I tried so much methods but I don't get success
and I'm aware used `First();` method, I mean cannot create loop about it, anyway, revelant
web page here this: http://www.planecrashinfo.com/recent.htm
thanks already
my new codes the following
i don't know  how i sync he said way

```java
private class FetchImageLogo extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        Bitmap bitmap;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            progressDialog.setTitle("LOGO");
            progressDialog.setMessage("Logo Çekiliyor...");
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try{
                getAllImages(yemekURL);

                for (int i = 0; i < imagesURLs.size(); i++) {
                    Glide.with(activity_main)
                            .load(imagesURLs.get(i))
                            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                            .skipMemoryCache(true)
                            .into(resimler);
                }
                /*
                Document doc  = Jsoup.connect(yemekURL).get();
                Element link = doc.select("img").first();
                String absHref = link.attr("abs:src"); // "http://jsoup.org/"
                InputStream input = new java.net.URL(absHref).openStream();
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);*/




            }catch (Exception e){

                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return null;
        }
        ArrayList<String> getAllImages(String url) {




            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // ToDo "Can not connect the URL, Make sure that the URL starts with [http://...]"
                return null;
            }

            Elements media = doc.select("[src]");
            Element link = doc.select("img").first();
            for (Element src : media) {
                if (src.tagName().equals("img")) {
                    // Add images url to the list
                    imagesURLs.add(link.attr("abs:src"));
                }
            }

            return imagesURLs;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {

            logo_layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.logo_layout);
            ImageView img_logo = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_logo);
            logo_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            img_logo.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
```

I dont know what i write this code beetwen scops `Glide.with(***activity_main***)`

Comment: post Logcat output and the way you invoke FetchImageLogo task please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to add this outside the application tag in your `AndroidManifest.xml`to access Internet.

   `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`
2. Add `Glide` and `Jsoup` libs to your project.
3. `activity_main.xml`

   ```
   <TextView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="First Image"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:textSize="18sp"/>

   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/imageView"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
   ```
4. `MainActivity.java`

   ```
   private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
   private ImageView imageView;
   private ArrayList<String> imagesURLs = new ArrayList<>();
   private String firstImgURL = "";

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_download_images);

       imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);

       new FetchImageLogo().execute();
   }

   private class FetchImageLogo extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
       //Bitmap bitmap;

       @Override
       protected void onPreExecute() {
           super.onPreExecute();

           progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
           progressDialog.setTitle("LOGO");
           progressDialog.setMessage("Logo Çekiliyor...");
           progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
           progressDialog.show();
       }

       @Override
       protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
           String yemekURL = "http://www.planecrashinfo.com/recent.htm";

           try {
               imagesURLs = getAllImages(yemekURL);

               // Can not get images URLs
               if (imagesURLs == null) return null;
           } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }

           // Display the first image...
           // you have to put your code in runOnUiThread() to reach UI components
           runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                   Glide.with(MainActivity.this)
                           .load(firstImgURL)
                           .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                           .skipMemoryCache(true)
                           .into(imageView);
               }
           });


           final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
           for (int i = 0; i < imagesURLs.size(); i++) {
               // ToDo: you need to create [RecyclerView] to display all images
               /*runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                   @Override
                   public void run() {
                       Glide.with(MainActivity.this)
                               .load(imagesURLs.get(i))
                               .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                               .skipMemoryCache(true)
                               .into(imageView);
                   }
               });*/

               stringBuilder.append("img").append(String.valueOf(i + 1)).append(": ")
                       .append(imagesURLs.get(i)).append("\n");
           }

           // See -> Logcat
           Log.d("Debug_Images", stringBuilder.toString());

           return null;
       }

       ArrayList<String> getAllImages(String url) {
           Document doc;

           try {
               doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
           } catch (IOException e) {
               // ToDo "Can not connect the URL, Make sure that the URL starts with [http://...]"
               return null;
           }

           // Get the first image URL
           Element link = doc.select("img").first();
           firstImgURL = link.attr("abs:src");

           // Get all images URLs
           Elements media = doc.select("[src]");
           for (Element img : media) {
               if (img.tagName().equals("img")) {
                   // Add images url to the list
                   imagesURLs.add(img.attr("abs:src"));
               }
           }

           return imagesURLs;
       }

       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
           /*logo_layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.logo_layout);
           ImageView img_logo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_logo);
           logo_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           img_logo.setImageBitmap(bitmap);*/
           progressDialog.dismiss();
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: thank you so much bro appricate it i can gettin all images urls but remain little bit problem im gettin error this phase .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)

Comment: You are maybe using emulator or device you have no access to the storage of the device you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
ArrayList<String> getAllImages(String url) {
    ArrayList<String> imagesURLs = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // ToDo "Can not connect the URL, Make sure that the URL starts with [http://...]"
        return null;
    }

    Elements media = doc.select("[src]");

    for (Element src : media) {
        if (src.tagName().equals("img")) {
            // Add images url to the list
            imagesURLs.add(image.attr("abs:src"));
        }
    }

    return imagesURLs;
}
```

Then you can use `Glide` library to download, cash and display the images using their URLs:

```
for (int i = 0; i < imagesURLs.size(); i++) {
    Glide.with(activity)
                .load(imagesURLs.get(i))
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                .skipMemoryCache(true)
                .into(imageView);
}
```

Comment: first of all thank you so much but i didn't solve problem honestly im not good at android reason is why i updated my codes can you check it out again